# Is it currently possible to have Views respect RSS Display settings on a Content Type?

Tags: 7, views, feeds

I have enabled and configured a 'Custom Display Setting' under 'Manage Display' of a content type for RSS

```
 admin/structure/types/manage/{my-type}/display/rss
```

I can't seem to find a way for Views to respect this new Display Setting.  The only available options for "Feed: Row style options" under a Feed View are:

```
Full text
Title plus teaser
Title only
Use Default RSS settings
```

None of which follow the Display options I specified for in the Content Type for RSS

Is there not currently a way to do this in D7? Does it require another module?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a current bug in views that does not respect any changes you make to the default RSS display settings. See Issue [#1301788: RSS Feed - Title plus teaser --- still grabs default node view?](http://drupal.org/node/1301788). There is a patch but it hasn't been rolled into a release yet.